# flask_jwt_extended not checking for X-CSRF-TOKEN in header

Tags: flask, flask-login, flask-jwt-extended

I have the following request being sent in React Native:

```
const getData = async (cookie) => {
    const resp = await fetch('/some_info');
    const data = await resp.json();
    console.log(data)
}
```

as you can see I purposefully did not add the appropriate header:

```
headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN':value,
            }
```

in the request because I wanted to verify that the GET request would fail without it.

The following are my configs:

```
JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRY_MINS = 15
JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRY_MINS = 1000
JWT_TOKEN_LOCATION = ['cookies']
JWT_COOKIE_CSRF_PROTECT = True
JWT_COOKIE_SECURE = False  # change to True in prod
```

And in my browser I can see the following relevant cookies:

[image]

The endpoint is defined as follows:

```
@app.route('/some_info', methods=['GET'])
@jwt_required
def get_some_info():
    user_identity = get_jwt_identity()
    name = get_user_name_from_identity()
    age = get_user_age_from_identity()
    return jsonify({
           'name': name,
           'age': age
    })
```

When the request happens, in the console log, I get a `200` and am able to see the json data. In the Request Headers (Using Chrome Inspector) I see that the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` is never set. Why is this happening/ why is the request going through ?

From JWT Extended Documentation:

```
# By default, the CRSF cookies will be called csrf_access_token and
# csrf_refresh_token, and in protected endpoints we will look for the
# CSRF token in the 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' header. You can modify all of these
# with various app.config options. Check the options page for details.
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in the documentation. CSRF protection only happen on methods that can mutate data, aka not `GET`

Here is the documentation:

```
JWT_CSRF_METHODS
The request types that will use CSRF protection. Defaults to ['POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
```

You can test that it works by adding `GET` to the list or calling a POST-type endpoint